# Getting data from SQL Server view through Entity Framework – Timeout Expired Error

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-view

Entity Framework connects to SQL Server views, but we're getting errors "Timeout expired". We could avoid the error by increasing the command timeout value and we're able to get the data, but it is taking more than 4 minutes for 100000 records. The view is created using 6 tables like

```
Header -> Items (Multiple) - > Details (Multiple)
```

We are getting an error some time

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

while executing selects against the SQL Server views through Entity Framework.

Native error code is 258

We increased the command timeout in the `DbContext` class and getting result for the first time execution however next time when we execute the same request it is taking more than 4 minutes.

```
public ClientContext(): base("Name = ClientDB")
{ 
    this.Database.CommandTimeout = 900;      
}
```

Has anyone come across the same situation and wanted to know why it is taking time when we execute the same request next time? Also, this is happening when we use the SQL Server views only.

Is there any way / suggestion to improve the performance each and every time we execute the request?

Comment: To be honest, it's going to be very difficult to improve the performance of a SQL View that we know nothing about.

Comment: If you want us to be able to *maybe* help - you'll need to share **at least** the complete table structures of all tables involved in that view, the view definition, and the code of how you're selecting data from that view in EF .....

Comment: I think you should be avoided using Views. Views degrade the LINQ query performance costly. These are slow in performance and impact the performance greatly.